# Rapid load and display of still images

Tags: windows, graphics, png, jpeg

I'm developing an app (Windows) that will allow essentially random access to about 1000 1920x1080 images. In effect this is a movie, but using stills and not presented sequentially -- the user can "scrub" to any image very rapidly.

I gather there are three factors to trade off: load time, decode time (if needed) and presentation time. I can specify the hardware, within limits, so SSD and good graphics card can be assumed.

Compressed images (PNG, JPG etc) will load more quickly but have an added decode step. Raw or BMP images will be slower to load but avoid the decode step. Presentation time should be the same in all cases, right, once in the proper form?

Is there an obviously superior approach, codec, library, hardware etc? Can anyone point to a study of the tradeoffs, or offer personal experience as a guide?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to decode single images fast enough to make them look like a movie. I hope for your sake I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom  Thanks. I did something very similar a few years ago when hardware was slower (especially drives), and with judicious skipping was able to keep a smooth flow. But this is a bit different. I don't need to make it play like a movie, I just need to be able to zip through a string of images and land on a chosen one. I'm looking for advice on where the bottleneck is likely to be and how to address it.

Comment: There's nothing that beats benchmarking when your requirements are critical, but I'll give you my unsubstantiated opinion anyway. I think we're still at the point where decoding is faster than reading, so go ahead and keep those compressed formats. I think a GPU based API will handily beat a window based one, so look to something like OpenGL.